# getting regex matching on semi-structured data - dat file

Tags: python, regex

I have this `dat file` that I need to get some information about the users in it.

The `file` looks like this:

```
USER john STATE 'RJ'
ID 123456 MAIL john@mail.com
PRIVILEGES                  STATUS  COMPUTER
    office docker cluster1  ACTIVE  WINDOWS  

USER maria STATE 'SP'
ID 987654 MAIL maria@mail.com
PRIVILEGES                   STATUS    COMPUTER
    financial-server office  INACTIVE  WINDOWS   

USER clarke STATE 'SP'
ID 55555 MAIL clarke@mail.com
PRIVILEGES                                          STATUS    COMPUTER
    active-directory gsuite cluster1 cluster2 admin ACTIVE    UBUNTU
```

What I want to do is to get a `list` that have a `dictionary` having the user and its priviledges, something like:

```
{'john': ['office', 'docker', 'cluster1'], 'maria': ['financial-server', 'office'], 'clarke': ['active-directory', 'gsuite', 'cluster1', 'cluster2', 'admin']}
```

The names are the easy part, I already got them with

```
with open("users.dat") as open_file:
    data = open_file.read()

x = re.findall("USER ([^\s]+)", data)
```

But these privileges can be one or many, and I don't have any clue how to get then, to save in my `dictionary`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the prettiest code but this works:

```
t = """
USER john STATE 'RJ'
ID 123456 MAIL john@mail.com
PRIVILEGES                  STATUS  COMPUTER
    office docker cluster1  ACTIVE  WINDOWS

USER maria STATE 'SP'
ID 987654 MAIL maria@mail.com
PRIVILEGES                   STATUS    COMPUTER
    financial-server office  INACTIVE  WINDOWS

USER clarke STATE 'SP'
ID 55555 MAIL clarke@mail.com
PRIVILEGES                                          STATUS    COMPUTER
    active-directory gsuite cluster1 cluster2 admin ACTIVE    UBUNTU
"""

import re

names = re.findall(r"USER\s([a-z]+)\sSTATE", t)
activities = re.findall(r"\s+([a-z1-9\s\-]+)\s+(INACTIVE|ACTIVE)", t)
results = {}
for user,rights in zip(names,activities):
    results[user] = re.findall(r"\w+", rights[0])

print(results)
```

Basically, since each user should be listed and their rights, you can grab these independently. Then you can grab all of their rights before finding activity and then separate it out after.

output:

```
{'john': ['office', 'docker', 'cluster1'], 'maria': ['financial', 'server', 'office'], 'clarke': ['active', 'directory', 'gsuite', 'cluster1', 'cluster2', 'admin']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function to process each block of the file instead of relying on regex (assuming they are all going to be like those in the example):

```
def parse_user(user_string):
    lines = [l.strip() for l in user_string.split('\n')]
    # Get the name.
    name = lines[0].split(' ')[1]
    # Filter out blank strings and the final two entries.
    privileges = [p for p in lines[-1].split(' ') if p][:-2]
    return name, privileges

results = {n:ps for n, ps in [parse_user(user_string) in data.split('\n\n')]}

Out[30]: 
{'john': ['office', 'docker', 'cluster1'],
 'maria': ['financial-server', 'office'],
 'clarke': ['active-directory', 'gsuite', 'cluster1', 'cluster2', 'admin']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pattern like `\r|\n\s\s\s\s([a-z0-9\-]+\s)+` to match any number of words including numbers or hyphens but only lower case. Assuming that will work based on the example you provided. It looks first for a new line or return character and then four spaces.

So now you just need to take each group found and break it on spaces then assign it to the correct person.